# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'graphql/language' for @ensdomains/ensjs

Tags: reactjs, graphql, web3js, ethers.js

Getting this error despite having GraphQL installed on the project

*package.json*

```
{
 "@ensdomains/ensjs": "^3.0.0-alpha.58",
 "ethers": "^5.7.2",
 "graphql": "^16.6.0",
 "stream": "^0.0.2",
 "typescript": "^4.9.3",
 "wagmi": "^0.7.14",
}


ERROR in ./node_modules/@ensdomains/ensjs/dist/esm/GqlManager.mjs 73:77-103

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'graphql/language' in 'C:\Projects\verity_web\node_modules\@ensdomains\ensjs\dist\esm'
Did you mean 'index.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'graphql/language' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

[image]